# Getting Lines of Context after a search in batch or VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

So I have a text file with that's filled in this format

```
Identifier: NUMBER1
    Information1 = something
    Information2 = other something
    Information3 = more something

Indentified: NUMBER2
    Information1 = something
    Information2 = other something
    Information3 = more something
```

I've tried using findstr but, unlike grep, it can't give me lines of context.

How can I get lines of context so that I can search for other bits of information?

If I could I would install grep and awk and such for Windows, but this is a tool going out to others so I can only use what is native to the OS, in this case batch and VBS.

The equivalent unix expression of what I would like to do is as follows:

```
grep -A 4 "NUMBER1" file | grep "Information2" | awk ' { print $3 } ' #not sure if $3 or $2 off the top of my head
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in VBScript:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 2 Then
  WScript.Echo "Usage: " & WScript.ScriptName & " pattern filename"
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

Const Context = 3 'lines

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = WScript.Arguments(0)

n = 0
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(1))
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = f.ReadLine
  If re.Test(line) Then
    WScript.Echo line
    n = Context
  ElseIf n > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo line
    n = n - 1
  End If
Loop
f.Close
```

Hovever, this is just a very basic draft with a lot room for improvement (e.g. make the number of context lines a parameter, add before-context, etc.).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. I'm a complete VBS nub (only know sh and python). I will edit this to make it more suitable for my needs, but it is exactly what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ECHO off&SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "NUMBER1" file') DO SET "skip=%%a"
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%b IN ('more +%skip% file ^| findstr "Information2"') DO IF NOT DEFINED line SET "line=%%c"
ECHO %line%
```

see also `findstr /?`.

Comment: See my edit. I know what findstr does. It does not provide me lines of context to do an additional findstr.

Comment: don't know, what `provide me lines of context` should be. My code provided a line already.

Comment: @Endoro "Context" means lines before or after the line with the match.

Comment: @Endoro Without knowing the content of those lines.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I leave the job to put patterns in variables for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a fairly old system, you probably have Windows [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) installed.  With Powershell, you can do something similar to grep, as follows:

```
Get-Content <filename> | Where-Object {$_ -like "*<pattern>*"}
```

Comment: I've asked about powershell already (believe me I have), since we can't 100% guarantee clients will have it, I can't use it. Otherwise I would have just done Select-String -context

Comment: @ardentsonata A few years ago, I would have agreed.  Today, it seems unlikely that a Windows user would not have powershell, since it has shipped as an integral part of the OS since 2009.  This is particularly true if you're dealing with professional or corporate clients. Basically, if you're dealing with a Win 7 system that is less than five years old, it's going to have powershell installed.

Comment: I don't disagree. But it's not a requirement my superiors want to add, so I can't use it. I'm stuck with using the lowest common denominator for everyone to ensure full compatibility.

Comment: @ardentsonata Understood.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rather useful grep-like tool which is a helper batch file called findrepl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

```
type "file.txt"|findrepl "NUMBER2" /O:-0:+3
```

and you can search further from the window of search results.